# How is second scanf working after closing standard input

Tags: c, linux, io, file-descriptor

How is the second scanf working in the below code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[256];
    int i;

    write(1, "Hello World\n", strlen("Hello World\n"));
    dup(0);
    close(0);
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("Buffer:%s\n", buf);
    dup(3);
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("Buffer:%s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

We are closing the stdin (fd:0), Then how does dup(3) have the effect of reopening the stdin?

Comment: Look at the return value of `dup`.

Comment: How do you know that `stdin` were reopened? Did you tried the code? Where are your proofed results? I can´t see anything of that in the question.

Comment: scanf used stdin (fd:0) and second scanf is successful

Comment: @md.jamal What is the exact input and output? There are still missing details.

Comment: Whatever input you provide in the second scanf will be displayed in printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you check the return value of these two call of dup, you will find the first is 3, and the second is 0. So before the second scanf function is called, file descriptor 0 is related with terminal again.

Comment: That's correct . We are closing stdin, by calling close(0). How is dup linking it again with stdin?

Comment: @md.jamal `dup` just uses the lowest-numbered unused descriptor for the new descriptor. You should understand that only if descriptor 0 is open can `scanf` work correctly. After you dup(0) which returns 3, stdin has two references, so then you `close(0)`, stdin is still open. Next you `dup(3)`, at this time stdin has a reference with file descriptor 3, after `dup(3)` returns, you get file descriptor 0 referred with stdin again. So at that time, scanf can correctly work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `dup` says that it uses "the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor for the new descriptor." Since you just closed FD 0, the next time you use `dup`, 0 will be the lowest-numbered unused file descriptor, so that's where the duplicate FD will end up. And since you put back exactly what you got rid of, `scanf` is happy to work again after doing so.